# prolog - ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog

I'm fairly new to prolog and need to check if the points makes a triangle isosceles but i got this error. ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

distance seems to work fine but the problem is with the isosceles.

```
   /*Is the triangle isosceles?*/
isosceles(point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), point2d(X3,Y3)):- 
    distance( point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), D ) =:= distance( point2d(X2,Y2), point2d(X3,Y3), D );
    distance( point2d(X2,Y2), point2d(X3,Y3), D ) =:= distance( point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X3,Y3), D );
    distance( point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X3,Y3), D ) =:= distance( point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), D ).

distance(point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), D):-
    D is sqrt((X2 - X1)^2 + (Y2 - Y1)^2).



?- isosceles(point2d(0,0), point2d(2,4), point2d(5,0)).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] distance(point2d(0,0),point2d(2,4),_10064)=:=distance(point2d(2,4),point2d(5,0),_10084)
ERROR:   [10] isosceles(point2d(0,0),point2d(2,4),point2d(5,0)) at /home/checkman123/prolog-geometry/threepoints.pl:25
ERROR:    [9] <user>
```

EDIT: so I think i got it working? by using , instead. I still wants to know why =:= doesnt work tho.

Comment: It doesn't work because `distance( point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), D )`  doesn't evaluate to a numeric value that can be compared with `=:=`. Instead, `D` is instantiated with the value that you want to have in the comparison. So you have to insantiate a `D1` on one hand, a `D2` on the other and then call `D1 =:= D2`. The error is currently misleading, it seems `=:=` doesn't get involved until both left and right side are grounded, which is not the case. Once they are it would still complain "`distance/3` is not a function".

Comment: i see thx! @DavidTonhofer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what David is saying, after factorizing the repeated calculations:

```
iso(point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), point2d(X3,Y3)):- 
    distance( point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), D12 ),
    distance( point2d(X2,Y2), point2d(X3,Y3), D23 ),
    distance( point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X3,Y3), D13 ),
    (D12 =:= D13; D23 =:= D13; D13 =:= D12).
```